# Knock out foreach binding from object array

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am new in knockout. I want to make the list of students.

I have attached the list structure which returned from MVC as an [image, Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYeEK.png).

***Js code:***

```
var employeeListViewModel = {};
var employeeViewModel = {
    id: "",
    name: ko.observable("neenu"),
    age: ko.observable(),
    email: ko.observable(),
    department: ko.observable(),
    address: {
        address1: ko.observable(),
        city: ko.observable(),
        State: ko.observable()
    },
};
var employeePageViewModel = {
    employee: employeeViewModel,
    employees: employeeListViewModel
};
var dataSource = {
    getemployees: function () {
        getData("Employee/GetEmployees").then((data) => {
            var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.data);
            employeeListViewModel = result();
            console.log(employeeListViewModel);
        });
    },
    init: function () {
        this.getemployees();
    }
}.init();
ko.applyBindings(employeePageViewModel);
```

***Html code:***

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

When I run this page ,It is neither displaying any error nor displaying data. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `employeeListViewModel` must be a `ko.observableArray()`
2) also when getting the result from your `getData` function just set the `observableArray` to the list:

```
employeeListViewModel(data.data); //assuming data.data is a [].
```

3) `ko.mapping.fromJS(data.data);` can be removed